# Problemas con validación de FORM con JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

Estoy teniendo problemas con el armado de un JS, es una validación de un formulario cuando realiza el envío no esta mostrando el mensaje.

Al no completar los campos la ejecución del mensaje de error se genera sin problemas, pero al llenar los campos y enviar no muestra el mensaje "gracias..."
Creo que estoy formulando mal el script.

```js
$(function(){ $("#btnSubmit").on("click", function(e){

  var errorMessage  = $(".errorMessage");
  var validMessage  = $(".validMessage");

  var hasError = false;
  var hasvalid = true;

  $(".inputValidation").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    if($this.val() == ""){
      hasError = true;
      $this.addClass("inputError");
      errorMessage.html("<p>Por favor, complete los siguientes campos.</p>");
      e.preventDefault();
    }if($this.val() != ""){
      $this.removeClass("inputError"); 

    }else{
      return true; alert(1);
      }

    }); //Input
 

  validMessage.slideDown(700);

  $(".inputValidation").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    if($this.val() == ""){
      hasvalid = false;
      $this.addClass("inputError");
      validMessage.html("<p>Por favor, complete los siguientes campos.</p>");
      e.preventDefault();
    }if($this.val() != ""){
      $this.removeClass("inputError"); 

    }else{
      return true; alert(1);
      }

    }); //Input
  validMessage.slideDown(700);

    /*ajax*/
  if(hasError == false){
      Ecommerce = document.getElementById("exampleInputEcommerce").value;
      Nombre = document.getElementById("exampleInputNombre").value;
      Telefono = document.getElementById("exampleInputPhone").value;
      Email = document.getElementById("exampleInputEmail1").value; 
      data2= { 
          ecommerce:Ecommerce,
          nombre:Nombre,
          telefono:Telefono,
          email:Email,
          tarea: "envio"
        };

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"envio.php",
        data: data2,
        success:function(data){
          
          /*$('#respuesta').fadeOut('fast').html(
            "Gracias, se a enviado su mensaje"
          );*/

        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
          $('.validMessage').fadeOut('fast').html(
            "Gracias, se ha enviado su mensaje"
          );
          $(".inputValidation").val("");
        } 

      });

  }




}); //Form .submit
});
```

```css
.info-section .imagen-formulario{
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}


.info-section .inputError{
 background-color: #9e46578c!important;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #824747!important;
  color: #fff;
}
.info-section .inputError::-webkit-input-placeholder{
  color: #fff;
}

.info-section .errorMessage{
 /*background-color: #d03e3e; */
    color: #fff;
    clear: right;
    display: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 55px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    margin-top: 21px;
}
.info-section .validMessage{
 /*background-color: #d03e3e; */
    color: #fff;
    clear: right;
    display: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 55px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    margin-top: 21px;
}
.info-section .errorMessage p{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 19px 0px 0px 30px;
  text-align: left;
}

.info-section .validMessage{
 /*background-color: #d03e3e; */
    color: #fff;
    clear: right;
    display: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 55px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    margin-top: 29px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 19px 0px 0px 30px;
  text-align: left;

    display: block!important;
}
.info-section .validMessage p{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 19px 0px 0px 30px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="info-section">
  <form class="formValidation px-lg-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="name" class="form-control inputValidation" id="exampleInputEcommerce" aria-describedby="Ecommerce" placeholder="Ecommerce">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="name" class="form-control inputValidation" id="exampleInputNombre" aria-describedby="Nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="phone" class="form-control inputValidation" id="exampleInputPhone" aria-describedby="phone" placeholder="Teléfono">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mb-5">
      <input type="email" class="form-control inputValidation" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email">
    </div>

    <button type="button" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn_enviar_form mt-sm-5">ENVIAR</button>

  </form>

  <div class="errorMessage"></div>

  <div class="validMessage" id="respuesta"></div>
</div>











<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: No entiendo 2 cosas 1: pk recorres tus inputs 2 veces con .each para hacer la misma operación y 2: pk no vacias el div donmde muestras los errores en cuanto verifiques que no hay, los preventDefault dentro de tus each tampoco los entiendo y lo que pongas detras de un return como el alert(1) nunca se ejecutara.

Comment: Si es que soy medio nuevo con Javascript y quizás este formulando mal el script.

Comment: estoy medio aprendiendo y este ejemplo lo tome de un ejemplo también.

Comment: Si pones un alert('algo') en la linea despues del if(hasError == false){ y llenas todos los campos, te muestra la alerta????

Comment: Si me muestra el alert() si completo los campos.

Comment: Entonces cambia tu success y error por success: function(){ alert('todo bien'); }, error: function(){ alert('Ha ocurrido un error'); } y mira ver ke sucede con el ajax, verifica que no existan errores en la consola de tu navegador

Comment: Emm no me funciono creo que algo estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Revisa la consola del navegador en busca de algun error o en el apartado de Red en XHR a ver si se hizo el ajax

Comment: Mira ahi arme algo, lo unico que nose como agregarle por ejemplo un tiempo al mensaje de cuando envia para que se muestre un rato y desaparezca.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){ $("#btnSubmit").on("click", function(e){

  var errorMessage  = $(".errorMessage");
  var validMessage  = $(".validMessage");
  errorMessage.html("");
  validMessage.html("");
  var hasError = false;
  var hasvalid = true;

$(".inputValidation").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    if($this.val() == ""){
      hasError = true;

      $this.addClass("inputError");
      errorMessage.html("<p>Por favor, complete los siguientes campos.</p>");
      e.preventDefault();
    }if($this.val() != ""){
      $this.removeClass("inputError"); 

    }else{
      return true; 
    }

    }); //Input
 

  errorMessage.slideDown(700);

  if(hasError == false){
      Ecommerce = document.getElementById("exampleInputEcommerce").value;
      Nombre = document.getElementById("exampleInputNombre").value;
      Telefono = document.getElementById("exampleInputPhone").value;
      Email = document.getElementById("exampleInputEmail1").value; 
      data2= { 
          ecommerce:Ecommerce,
          nombre:Nombre,
          telefono:Telefono,
          email:Email,
          tarea: "envio"
        };

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"envio.php",
        data: data2,
        success:function(data){
          
          /*$('#respuesta').fadeOut('fast').html(
            "Gracias, se a enviado su mensaje"
          );*/

        },
        
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
          $('.validMessage').fadeOut('fast').html(
            "Gracias, se a enviado su mensaje"
          );
          $(".inputValidation").val("");
        } 

      });

  }

}); //Form .submit
});
```